# "should always and always", Is it a idiomatic expression, is it informal or formal?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This video is saying (https://youtu.be/yXJYRlxkfu4?t=407)

> So remember when you use a verb immediately
>   after *as well as* it should always and always be in the ‘ing’ form.

I googled ["should always and always"](https://www.google.com/search?bih=718&biw=1536&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&hl=en&sxsrf=ACYBGNTXRPZhlMwmCkCDX4FHKVzc9jNT1Q%3A1582071152898&ei=cH1MXt-8Nq7xhwPmzoXoBw&q=meaning%20of%20%22should%20always%20and%20always%22&oq=meaning%20of%20%22should%20always%20and%20always%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i71l8.0.0..2982836...0.6..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.tpoIe0rpzLw&ved=0ahUKEwjftM-oqtznAhWu-GEKHWZnAX0Q4dUDCAs) and found lots of people use this expression.

Is it a idiomatic expression, is it informal or formal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fifty years of speaking English, I have never heard this expression.

I have heard `should always, always`, but it's pretty informal.